# Azure WebApp VS Azure Function

Tags: c#, funções, asp.net-core, microsoft-azure

Quais são as maiores diferenças entre webapp e function?

A principio, sei que webapp suporta quantidades de dados mais elevadas que a funtion, e que a function tem outras formas de ativação como queue, trigger, etc.

Porem, além dessas diferenças, a algo a mais?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu diria que a principal diferença está nos paradigmas.

A ideia principal para utilização de Azure Functions são em cenários reativos, onde uma ação ou evento, irá iniciar a execução de sua function. Por este motivo, ao hospedá-las no modo por consumo, sua aplicação não estará em execução 100% do tempo.
Existe um delay entre o evento/ação e a execução da function, este "problema" é conhecido como cold start.

Caso você possua um App Service Plan, você também pode hospedar suas functios neste App Service Plan, e o cold start será minimizado.

Já os WebApps, como dito, são mais utilizados para hospedagem de APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Quanto ao Azure Functions ele trabalha em um paradigma orientado a funções em uma plataforma serverless (sem servidor, onde não quer dizer propriamente que não há servidor físico, mas sim que o provisionamento dele é dinâmico: [Azure Sem Servidor](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/solutions/serverless/#overview)).

Quanto a um Web App, trata-se de uma solução para hospedagem de aplicações web (Comumente APIs), é possível utilizar os recursos das Azure Functions em um Web App para orientar determinadas ações por eventos.